# Nvidia Driver Install on Centos 7 Results in Black Screen

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, centos-7

I have followed the steps from this guide (https://linuxconfig.org/nvidia-geforce-driver-installation-on-centos-7-linux-64-bit) and at the end I have a black screen instead of gnome desktop.

Which log files can I check to figure out what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
An example of a fix that worked for me:

lspci | grep VGA => get *hex* numbers at beginning of NVIDIA line
convert to *decimal*, all semi-colons (e.g., 21:00.0 => 33:0:0)
vi /etc/X11/xorg.conf => add BusID num in "Device" section
#-------------------------------------------------------------------
Section "Device"
    ...
    BusID          "PCI:33:0:0"
    Option         "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
    ...
EndSection
#-------------------------------------------------------------------
reboot
```